# Нет прокрутки при уходе элемента за пределы экрана

Tags: прокрутка, выравнивание, центрирование

**Вопрос**: Как сделать так, чтобы появлялась полоса прокрутки влево?

**Суть**: Есть элемент, который всегда выравнивается по центру видимой области через `top`, `left` (50%) и `translate` (-50%, -50%). Но у элемента фиксированные ширина и высота, соответственно, когда размер видимой области меньше площади элемента, часть элемента скрывается за левой частью окна браузера, и полоса прокрутки влево не появляется.

Как можно это исправить?

Желательно без сторонних библиотек js, да и вообще без js, если возможно.

Comment: Нужен пример кода, из описания неясна проблема

Comment: а где код?:?????

Answer (score 1):

Используйте для центрирования по горизонтали не translate а просто margin: 0 auto; И проблема будет решина.

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: blue;
}

.object {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.object2 {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="object"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="object2"></div>
</div>
```